# Can I run control and line voltage together in my circumstance?

Tags: ac, dc, wiring

I have one vessel which holds 1.5 gallons of water. It has a stainless steel (SS) bottom with a 500w 120VAC @ 4.17a silicone heat pad adhered to the exterior SS bottom to heat the water. Also, in the bottom compartment of the vessel I have 10.5w 5VDC @ 2.1a LED lights. There is a separate power tower which has one short (8") 16 gauge AC computer power cord which connects to one side of the vessel for the said silicone heat pad. On the other side of the independent power tower there is one short (8") DC cord that connects to the other side of the vessel for the said LED lights.

Problem: two cords (a DC cord on the left of the vessel and an AC cord on the right side of the vessel) coming from the power tower to the vessel look really ugly. I want to make it look better by running both the AC wires and DC wires together in one shrink tube sheath thereby making one AC/DC power cord instead of two sperate power cords.

Question: Can I do this? Or, does this article that I found on the subject apply to my situation whereby I should not do this? Thank you in advance for any advice you have including if there is any another way to have just one cable in lieu of two:

https://inside.lighting/news/22-03/can-control-and-line-voltage-wires-be-run-same-conduit#

[image]

Comment: You know that AC mains power equipment needs a fairly serious enclosure to protect people from shock and equipment from damage.  Will the low-voltage circuit be *entirely, 100%* inside such AC power-rated cables and enclosures, every inch of it?  That link is really obsessed with interference.  That may be *their* issue, but it's not *the* issue.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica
Yes, I was planning on using 16AWG strand wire bare copper wire for both the AC and DC like this:
https://www.acerracing.com/products/superworm-silicone-wire-16-gauge. 

Yes, the four wires would be 100% AC power-rated with a 4-wire AC rated connector at each end. 

Thank you for your interest in helping me.

PS: if I could get by with 18AWG, that's even better.

Comment: And, yes, I'm using the factory AC rated enclosures. Hence, I wont modify the enclosure other than changing the panel mount I/Os to fit the new 4-wire connecters.

Comment: Don't do that. Don't raid the "parts bins" for your other hobbies instead of using proper AC rated wire.  You want SO or SW rated *cordage* of 14/4 or 12/4 type.  Any respectable electrical supply and a few hardware stores will sell it for about a buck a foot *the whole cable*, not a buck a foot *per wire* (wow).  If you want to use electrical wires inside a mains-rated conduit, then use #12 THHN which any better hardware store sells for a quarter a foot.   On the DC power, I'm asking will there be ANY point where the DC power is not inside a mains-rated enclosure, cable or conduit?

Comment: And you will be running safety ground, right?  Nominally 5 wires, though if the DC power supply is UL Listed, I see no problem using safety ground as Vss/-/"gnd" for the low voltage. EVs do that.

Comment: Hi there, I'm on the road working some serious hours. I will be back Sunday and answer your questions more thoroughly after my return.  I really do appreciate you helping me. Thank you.

Comment: in the meantime, I found yet another article on this same topic. It appears there are some codes (at least in South Africa, UK and India) not allowing this. Not sure if the US code allows this or not. Again, I'm not smart enough to understand this which is why I'm posing here. will post again Sunday:
 https://www.ecosoch.com/can-dc-and-ac-cables-run-in-same-conduit/#

Comment: Well, I was forced to take a break because I received a call from an EE friend as to that last article link I posted. He has never heard of this... "The answer is No since the DC cables could induce a DC voltage onto the AC side" but rather the other way around in that AC cables could induce AC voltage into the DC side. He said he thinks the author might have gotten his story twisted and said it is his opinion as long as I use shielded wire that running both the AC/DC wires in the same cable should pose no problem. As far as code goes, he was uncertain to the US or UL code that may cover this.

Comment: And, one other thought he had....he said after I price the 5 pin I/O connectors as compared to the standard consumer electronics 3 pin connectors that I might should consider leaving well enough alone and stay with two separate cables. I will post photos of my application so you and others will better understand what is is I'm working on which may help your advice in this regard. Now back to work.

Comment: Correct about the root of the problem: AC power getting onto the DC circuit *and then leaving AC-rated enclosures/wires* is the critical problem.  Like putting 120V on an Ethernet wire!  Yes, finding appropriate 4-pin connectors may be a hassle. You could use NEMA 14-30 or Euro 3-phase connectors for instance and use L2 for low voltage DC, but you're in the soup if someone plugs that into a generator!  If it's hardwired, conduit makes that easy.

Comment: What does that mean in #3 above in the image I just added to my original post?

Comment: FYI, this product will be shipped worldwide. I'll post photos this weekend. My PCB designer is asking me this question:  Would be good to ask someone that know well the NEC code and US regulations.

If there is no problem to run the DC and AC at same conduit we can keep one board at tower.
But will have only one connector or separated connectors? Need to check if is not prohibited AC and DC at same connector.

Comment: The company I am working for on this product development project will not allow me to post photos. We have come to a conclusion on this matter. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The NEC rule is this: As long as the entire low voltage circuit (including everything that connects conductively to that circuit) is handled the same way an AC mains power circuit would be handled, inside mains-rated cables and mains-rated enclosures, then the low voltage power can intermix with mains AC circuits.

What you can't do, for instance, is connect to an Ethernet port and then route it (on decidedly (non-mains-rated) Ethernet cable into a switch that is definitely not rated for 230V on the ethernet, to PCs that are not rated for 230V on their ethernet port etc.  When you need to make that kind of transition, you need to do it on components rated for that service.

The general concern is some sort of problem causing the low voltage wiring to be energized at an AC mains voltage, and then spreading onto wiring, sockets or equipment not rated for it.

Ultimately if you are selling a thing internationally, you will need to conform with the governments' rules for such equipment. For instance you need to do all the things required to lawfully put a "CE" mark on an item sold in Europe (not just stamp CE on everything, like *some countries' vendors*, not naming any names).  In certain countries particularly in the Americas,  you will need independent 3rd party testing lab certification of that compliance. Unfortunately in those countries the standards are paywalled.  CSA writes the standards in Canada and UL writes the standards in USA. **We see many projects fail because this paragraph was disregarded, or considered too late in the design process for blunders to be avoided. Certification needs to be front-of-mind from day one; trying to "bolt it on" afterwards is unreliable.**

Comment: Thank you for your well thought out and informative answer including your comments on CE and UL certification. You've really helped me out in this process.

Comment: Also, for those who might refer to this thread later in the USA...although it is a good thing to design and build to CE and UL standards as for safety and liability reasons, as Harper recommends, it is not necessary to get such certifications for consumer products in the USA. The company I work for will release their main product to the consumer market without such certifications and apply for those certifications later when they can afford it: https://coastlabel.com/ul-listed-vs-ul-certified/

Comment: @tayglo Think so? Ask your insurance company whether they will underwrite product liability claims or "implied warranty of merchantability" claims. Yes, the government lacks the enforcement resources to go after direct-mail sellers, especially those who bounce it through China. Manufacturers always want to believe it's legal, and this area of law is complicated enough that there's plenty of room for obfuscation and self-delusion.  It's very hard to retrofit compliance, you need compliance experts involved as early as possible.

Comment: Here are a few of the quotes from the factual article on this subject:

"Just as with UL Listed and UL Recognized, there are no laws requiring UL certification before a product can be sold in the US. However, receiving UL certification helps you ensure the quality of your product as well as its safety for consumers."

"There is no law in the United States requiring products sold in the US to be certified by UL or another NRTL."

"Just as there are no laws requiring products to be UL Listed, there are no laws requiring components to be UL Recognized." 

It is what it is.

Comment: There is no need to bounce anything through China. And it has nothing to do with the Government lacking resources to go after companies who are in fact, abiding by the law by not electing to participate in the money racket CE and UL certifications until a later date when startups have a bigger budget to participate in the certification process. Before the 21st Century and direct sales, when the big box stores controlled the consumer market, startups were forced to get such certifications. However, since the internet and direct sales, UL has become much less relevant.

Comment: As far as insurance underwriters, I'm not sure about that. But I can only assume since the company I'm working for (their prior company was acquired by Warren Buffett) as well as the majority of US startups that choose not to get UL and CE certifications until later after their products are already on the market, that product liability insurance is not an issue so long as they have PE's signing off on the design which is designed to UL and CE standards and only lacks those respective certifications.

Comment: In fact, one can make a STRONG case that a PE's seal of approval is just as good or better than UL and CE certifications because that can easily be tracked back to the PEs who signed off on the design as opposed to the massive fraud surrounding UL and CE certifications which are difficult to trace. Also, because the certification labs have become so money oriented, they are more susceptible to corruption and certifying inferior products than individual PEs who are putting their name and rep on the line.  I am much more comfortable having a team of engineers seal of approval vs UL or CE.

Comment: Here's the point: Compliance can't be retrofit.  It has to be front-of-mind from conception or you can all-too-easily paint yourself into a corner and find yourself *unable* to certify without sacrificing a keystone feature (e.g. a Sense/Curb home energy monitor with an ethernet port - relevant to our discussion).  **In fact, if you are filling a product gap in the marketplace, that gap may exist *because* nothing can fill that and still be certified**.

Comment: Understood and noted. Thanks for sharing your wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - should be considered a COMMENT not an ANSWER. Regards-

Lots of interesting NEC code discussion here.  My KISS perspective below. If both the  power cables were supplied with each of the heating and lighting control panels, it would seem logical that the cables are rated for the voltage level and type that they contain. I would expect the cables meet the NEC unless you have an outdoor installation and the systems are for use indoor, etc. (Or you have supplied your own cabling). Taking two cables and running them in parallel and holding them together with shrink sleeve or ty-wraps or 'string' is not considered installing them in a raceway (conduit). It may not be a best practice to run AC and DC wiring close together in parallel due to EMI induced into the DC wiring. If the cables are rated for their service, their insulation is appropriate and placing them next to each other does not necessarily affect the safety of the installation.  THE EMI that might be induced into the DC cable may affect the operation of the lighting system. I would suggest temporarily rerouting the cables to determine if any EMI affects the lighting system. All of these opinions are contingent on the existing cables being a part of the existing systems and noted systems are rated for the service they are being used in. Also AC and DC cables running in the same bundle can create a maintenance hazard if the maintenance personnel are expecting only AC or DC signals in the same cable bundle. Many times technicians are not as cautious when working around very low DC voltage as they are when working around AC. Re-reading additional responses from your post, I understand this may be an industrial skid type installation. My experience will be that a good electrical inspector or technician from the end user will not prefer the paralleled cables more from a typical 'best design and installation' practices perspective and less from a code perspective.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered. After much research it has been determined that as per the NEC exception, one can in fact run DC control voltage in the same cable as AC line voltage so long as one uses AC rated cable with a minimum of 16AWG which is the minimum DC wiring specification under 4.6 M @ 5A and under 1.8 M @ 10 A (see link to chart). Because my application is dealing with lengths under 1 foot and amperage under 5A, if I decide to go with one cable in lieu of two cables then I will use 16/5 AC rated cable (2 for AC; 2 for DC, and one for ground). The next question which I will ask on a new thread is; Does the NEC code allowing this mean that I can use one AC rated 5 pin I/O connector on each end of the cable or should I use two AC rated 3 pin I/O connectors on each end of the cable? Thank you to Harper and James P for your participation. I did not address safety because that wasn't my question. If I have safety  concerns then I will post a question on that issue if I can't find the answer on my own. https://www.bluesea.com/resources/1437